# Showing sequential scan result instead of the index

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing, sequential

while I am analyzing my Postgres SQL query it gave me  an issue, it always gave sequential scan result instead of the index and we already increase the memory of the Postgres database and vacuum it but we didn't get any positive result here is the query that we executed and the result we got
Query

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT *
FROM "Geography".regions where "type" ='City'
Result:
Seq Scan on regions  (cost=0.00..25934.28 rows=84979 width=1099) (actual time=0.010..38.759 rows=85245 loops=1)
  Filter: ((type)::text = 'City'::text)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 8217
Planning Time: 0.103 ms
Execution Time: 42.257 ms
```

Comment: Your query returns almost all rows from the table. A Seq Scan is the fastest way to do that.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 2):

well, execution plan shows only 8% of the rows are filtered out by your condition,meaning 92% of the rows in that table are going to be returned so Seq Scan is much faster when most of the rows are supposed to be returned ,
and that's why optimizer never bother scanning the index